# Deserialize property as a value to c#

Tags: c#, .net, json

You can not undo the following json code for a class c # the property is not a name is an incremental code or identifier.

server result.

```
{
    "success": 0,
    "persona": {
        "1000": {
            "nombre": "Nombre 1",
            "apellido": "Apellido 1",
            "edad": 18
        },
        "1001": {
            "nombre": "Nombre 2",
            "apellido": "Apellido 2",
            "edad": 18
        }
    }
}
```

the server response could be converted to the next valid format.

```
{
    "success": 0,
    "persona": [
        {
            "id": "1000",
            "nombre": "Nombre 1",
            "apellido": "Apellido 1",
            "edad": 18
        },
        {
            "id": "1001",
            "nombre": "Nombre 2",
            "apellido": "Apellido 2",
            "edad": 18
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Because if the question is "how do I deserialise this JSON (i.e. the first block)?" then that is very easy to answer.

Comment: Try deserializing Persona as a `Dictionary<string, CreateYourTypeForPersonaElements>` or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deserialize the "persona" property to a Dictionary. The C# classes would look something like this:

```
public class Response 
{
    public int Success { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Persona> Persona { get; set; }
}

public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public int Edad { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization using Json.net:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks, working correctly